How to check if a set of numbers matches a Beta (4,4) distribution?
I have a random number generator that should generate values based on a Beta 4,4 distribution and some minimum and maximum. (IE, values between 0.9 and 1.1)
I can generate a large set of numbers using it fairly quickly.
How can I check if the generator is behaving as expected? What statistical test could I run on the samples?
I can use tools such as Excel to calculate things like mean, variance, skewness, kurtosis, min, max, etc. I can also whip up scripts using C++ or Python to parse the data if an existing library would be useful here.

For continuous distributions like this one, the standard mechanism is to use the probability integral transform to convert the results to (putatively) uniform values between $0$ and $1$ and then apply any of the myriad tests of uniformity and randomness, such as those offered by standard testing suites.  Make sure to read the comment thread to that question.

Should be fairly simple to code up a quantile-quantile plot in python.
If you can generate lots of numbers, then do so because the more you have the better the estimated quantiles will be.  Here is an example in python
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import beta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## Generate 1000 draws from a beta distribution
data = beta.rvs(a=4, b=4, size = 10_000)

q = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
observed_quantiles = np.quantile(data, q=q)
real_quantiles = beta.ppf(q, a=4, b=4) 

plt.plot(observed_quantiles, real_quantiles, 'o')
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1])
plt.show()

The dots lay on the $y=x$ line, so the estimated quantiles from sampling agree with the theoretical quantiles.


This plot is good, thanks. Is there a way to get a defensible number I can report to others as to how well the results fit to this line?

See our threads on this topic.  Additional good search terms include Kolmogorov-Smirnov (aka KS) and Shapiro-Wilk.  There are subtleties; in particular, the test has to be modified when you estimate the bounds of your distribution from the data.

I've noticed that both your original graph and my own answers have two outlier dots on either end. Lower on the left, higher on the right. What does this represent?

One other question: linspace generates numbers evenly from 0 to 1 there, and it's passed as the probability for the quantile to use. Wouldn't that imply all numbers from 0 to 1 are equally probable? But that's not true for a Beta distribution. Am I missing something?

Outliers are the points which generate the smallest/largest quantile.  I've passed a linearly spaced vector to the ppf method, which means I'm getting the percentiles of the beta distirbution, which are not evenly spaced.
